# List --> Item Renderer (ComboBox) Dispatch Event catched based on number of items in the List

Tags: actionscript-3, list, combobox

I have List defined in an MXML component like this

```
<s:VGroup initialize="init();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void {
                stack.addEventListener(customEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, listenerFunc)
            }
            private set dataProvider(dp:ArrayCollection): void {
                this.dp = dp
            }
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem label="customLabel: "
            <s:List id="stack"
                    dataProvider="{dp}"
                    itemRenderer="comboBoxEditor"
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
```

My itemRenderer is

```
<s:ItemRenderer>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function changeHandler(e:ListEvent):void {
                Alert.show(String(e));
                owner.dispatchEvent(new customEvent(customEvent.CUSTOME_EVENT, cb.selectedIndex));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:ComboBox id="cb"
                 dataProvider="{data}" 
                 change="changeHandler(event)" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The dp in List is an ArrayCollection of ArrayCollection like this

```
a = new ArrayCollection()
a.addItem({label: "a"})
a.addItem({label: "b"})
dp = new ArrayCollection()
dp.addItem(a)
```

Every time I make a change in the combobox selection, an event is created and dispatched appropriately as expected. But the eventListener in the owner or the parent List only catches the change event related to first item i.e "a" in the combo box? If I select b, an event is created but not catched by the owner list "stack"....
what am I doing wrong ??

Thanks in advance

If I do another
    dp.addItem(a)

Then in the second combo box, I trigger catch event listener event for both "a" abd "b" selected. The first combo box also starts working....

In essence based on my extensive trial runs, based on the number of items in "dp" and "a", catch event is triggered a certain number of times only depending on number of items in "dp"

Comment: Where are you set dataProvider for stack?

Comment: dataProvider is set up in the script.... I added that part of pseudocode....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reproduce your problem, but all works fine to me. And I really don't see mistakes in your code. Maybe my working example will help you.

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:local="*" >
    <local:CustomComponent />
</s:Application>
```

CustomComponent.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" initialize="init()">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        private function init():void {
            stack.addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT, listenerFunc);
            var a:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            a.addItem({label: "a"});
            a.addItem({label: "b"});
            var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            dp.addItem(a);
            stack.dataProvider = dp;
        }

        private function listenerFunc(event:CustomEvent):void {
            trace("blah - " + event.index);
        }
        ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:List id="stack" itemRenderer="comboBoxEditor" />
</s:VGroup>
```

CustomEvent.as

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event {

        public static const EVENT:String = "customEvent";

        public var index:int;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, index:int, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false) {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this.index = index;
        }
    }
}
```

comboBoxEditor.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ListEvent;


        private function changeHandler(e:ListEvent):void {
            owner.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.EVENT, cb.selectedIndex));
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:ComboBox id="cb"
                 dataProvider="{data}"
                 change="changeHandler(event)" />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Yeap, for both. "blah - 1" when changed to "b" and "blah - 0" when changed back to "a".

Comment: I checked ur example its working, the way it should be... So it could be because my mxml components and editors are all over the places .... I dont know if that can create such problems,..... But I will wait a bit for more insight from other users if I can get before accepting ur answer.. Thanks

Comment: Yes the code is okay... I found the bug in somewhere else in some data manipulation in the listenerFunc... I put my alert at the bottom making me think that eventListener is not catching it... Thank you...